How to make the count up stops randomly after the start button is clicked in flutter
Countup(
 begin: 0,
 end: 100,
 duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
 separator: ',',
 style: TextStyle(
   fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
   fontSize: 22,
 ),
) 

This is my code above, how can I make the count up to stop automatically in a random way without the stop button click. There must be 2 ways for the timer to stop, e.g the user has to click stop at a certain figures or the count up stops automatically. Please help.
I had built the count up of numbers it's running perfectly, but i want it to stop automatically or the user has to click the stop button provided the user has not click the button the countup must stop automatically at random based

cant find any method, you can swap or remove the widget like if(true)HideMyView()

To generate a random integer with values between 0 and 5000, you could use:
import 'dart: math';

final rand = Random();
final milliseconds =  (rand.nextDouble() * 5000).toInt();

To stop the counter at a random duration, your function would then become:
Countup(
 begin: 0,
 end: 100,
 duration: Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds),
 separator: ',',
 style: TextStyle(
   fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
   fontSize: 22,
 ),
)


